# To be blunt bought bitcoin in 2009 at 25 cents have not touched it

Tags: blockchain, wallet, block, value

I am hoping you can help
I read through a few of you answers to other inquiries and as per my research you are very well versersed.

I acquired Bitcoin back when it first came out of trading at 0.0008 I cant remember the catalyst that popped it out bu was running equities trading desk at the time and was thinking it is stupid not to.

Peer pressure said no but still bought $25 at 8 cents it was in june 2009.  Our tech fellow got it done for me and asked if I wanted a wallet and my limited understanding said I wanted it to stay on the block chain.  Perhaps he did out in the Qt wallet at the time.

I have left it alone for so long but now worth a bunch so wanting to access it with prudence, if I can and it is still there.

I was smart enough to call my mom and have here put the codes in a family address book my sister happened to be there so it ain't no dream.

I will look back for a response and lets hope for a great end to the story.

Excuse the brevity and spelling errors

Regards,
Rainbow Dash

Answer (score 3):

Spending Bitcoins requires the knowledge of the private key corresponding to the address holding the funds. These keys are managed by each user individually. Without the key, the coins are rendered unspendable.

Given the lack of details, I assume that you no longer hold a copy of the wallet that held the private keys. If that is the case, your funds are lost. If my understanding is incorrect, please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Mr. Murch do in fact have the key

Comment: r. Murch do in fact have the key.  Can I ask you a question that may be naive, I guess I can.  When I bought the BTC I told my friend the computer guru to leave it in the blockchain and I did not want a wallet.  Is that possible?. If impossible. I then I assume my keys are for a wallet,,which would have been the QT wallet.  I have never opened it and sure security haxe changed but would I just got and log in?

Comment: Generally, "wallet" refers to software that manages keys and the corresponding balances. If you do in fact still have BitcoinQt on your computer, I would recommend that you first create a backup of the `wallet.dat` in your Bitcoin directory, and then, yes, you should indeed be able to open your software and see your funds. You would very likely need to synchronize with the network in order to spend, though. Also, the very first Bitcoin versions did not encrypt the wallet, so if you ever got hacked, your money might be gone. Do make a backup of the `wallet.dat` first, though.

Comment: If you actually still run a 2009 version of bitcoin-qt, you'd probably want to import the wallet to a new version to speed up the synchronization.